# Compass SCSS font-url configuration issue

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Am writing down a template with use of compass sass here the font-mixin makes some problem by without setting web font.And my config file is like

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "resources/stylesheets"
sass_dir = "resources/stylesheets" 
images_dir = "resources/images"
javascripts_dir = "resources/js"
```

and then by usage of font mixin generated output is

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "cabinregular";
src: url('resources/stylesheets/fonts/cabin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded- 
opentype'), url('resources/stylesheets/fonts/cabin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
 url('resources/stylesheets/fonts/cabin-regular.woff') format('woff');
 }
```

The path was correct but font won't apply while am running the html.But if i specify the http path like

```
   http_path="/somename/"
```

it applies. then why it won't works without specifying  the http_path..?

Comment: Maybe you should add fonts_dir. For example: fonts_dir = "fonts" or I think fonts_dir = "resources/fonts".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bringing  `src: url("../fonts/cabin-regular?#iefix");` before the main src make working fine

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'cabinregular';
  src: url("../fonts/cabin-regular?#iefix");
  src: url("../fonts/cabin-regular?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/cabin-regular") format("woff"), url("../fonts/cabin-regular") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/cabin-regular.svg#cabin-regular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```